# C++0x lambda, how can I pass as a parameter?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11

Please look at the following C++0x lambda related code:

```
typedef uint64_t (*WEIGHT_FUNC)(void* param);
typedef std::map<std::string, WEIGHT_FUNC> CallbackTable;

CallbackTable table;
table["rand_weight"] = [](void* param) -> uint64_t
{
  return (rand() % 100 + 1);
};
```

I got an error (in Visual Studio 2010) that the lambda couldn't be converted to the type of `WEIGHT_FUNC`. I also know the answer: using `std::function object`:

```
typedef std::function<uint64_t (void*)>  WEIGHT_FUNC;
```

However, I also want to know how I can receive the type of lambda WITHOUT using `std::function`. What type should it be?

Comment: auto will just be useful to automatically determine the type, it's not a variant type, it can't be a parameter.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? Seems your compiler is non-standard in regards to lambda's, they should be able to implicitly convert to a function pointer (in cases such as this.)

Comment: g++ 4.5 is fine with it, so i'm guessing VC10, for which i've already seen some lambda bugs.

Comment: [It's been fixed for the next release of Visual C++](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/572138)

Comment: @James: Ah, of course you had a bug open for it - i should have known :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The conversion to function pointer is relatively new: It was introduced with [N3043](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3043.html) on February 15, 2010.

While e.g. GCC 4.5 implements it, Visual Studio 10 was released on April 12, 2010 and thus just didn't implement it in time. As James pointed out, this [will be fixed](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/572138) in future releases.

For the moment you have to use one of the alternative solutions provided here.

Technically something like the following workaround would work, but without variadic templates its no fun to generalize it (Boost.PP to the rescue...) and there is no safety net against passing capturing lambdas in:

```
typedef uint64_t (*WeightFunc)(void* param);

template<class Func> WeightFunc make_function_pointer(Func& f) {
    return lambda_wrapper<Func>::get_function_pointer(f);
}

template<class F> class lambda_wrapper {
    static F* func_;
    static uint64_t func(void* p) { return (*func_)(p); }    
    friend WeightFunc make_function_pointer<>(F& f);    
    static WeightFunc get_function_pointer(F& f) {
        if (!func_) func_ = new F(f);
        return func;
    }
};

template<class F> F* lambda_wrapper<F>::func_ = 0;

// ...
WeightFunc fp = make_function_pointer([](void* param) -> uint64_t { return 0; });
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the conversion to function pointers is only for stateless lambda functions, they can not capture lexical scope.

Comment: The conversion to function pointer seems not to work with g++ 4.5 in template code (http://tinyurl.com/3y6hkyq)

Answer (score 1):

If you really insist on not using `function<>` then you could probably use decltype:

```
typedef decltype([](void*)->uint_64{return 0;}) my_lambda_type;
```

I really don't recommend this though since you're drastically limiting yourself and I don't even know if two lambda's with the same signature are guaranteed to be the same type.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the type generated will be the same than if you write the exact same typedef somewhere else? I don't think you should assume that the type is signature-dependent... but maybe i'm wrong.

Comment: Old answer, I know, but lambda expression's cannot appear in an unevaluated context. (I think the rationale being what you brought up: since each lambda expression is a unique, unspecified type, you aren't guaranteed any particular meaningful answer an an unevaluated context.)

Answer (score -1):

Try with (not tested) :

```
#include <function>

typedef std::function< int64_t (void*) > weight_func;
typedef std::map<std::string, weight_func > CallbackTable;
```

I don't think there is any other way to do this than to use std::function or equivalent.

Comment: Don't use `std::function<R (*)(T)>`, use `std::function<R (T)>`.

Comment: I already knew how to do it with std::function (please see my posting again). I was wondering whether there would be a way to convert lambda to function pointer w/o using std::function.

Comment: Strange, I had to include <functional>, not <function> for VS2010