# what does the compiler do on my method concerning type conversion

Tags: c++, type-conversion

Hey, I appreciate if you could tell me what the compiler does on my method. If I call it with `Area(10.1,10.1);` it returns me `102`. So the `.01` get cut? Do you have a good site where I can get information about this particular topic? thx for your time!

```
float Area (float length, float width){
int result;
result = length*width;
return result;
}
```

Comment: How, may I ask, should the compiler be able to tell the difference between your first and second parameters?

Comment: Why do you are assigning to an int?

Comment: This can't be correct, since you declare `length` twice, and that's ill-formed. Did you mean for that to be `length` and `width`?

Comment: @ChrisLutz: The Psychic++ compiler is at version 0.9.42 and is closing in on a 1.0 release Any Day Now™.  You often see it used on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Fred Nurk - Maybe Stack Overflow _is_ the compiler! Maybe SO is just the information database of an AI compiler that knows how to turn every single bit of bad code posted on SO into machine code that functions as expected. Maybe soon we can have the mythical "Do [task]." programming language. [insert singularity joke]

Comment: @ChrisLutz: SO is the Mechanical Turk of compilers.  Except we get meaningless points instead of pennies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're assigning the value of a float expression to an int, the data simply gets truncated upon assignment (but after the expression is evaluated).

Comment: so the method still receives a float back after conversion?

Comment: @DannyRe - Yes. You're converting the `float` answer to an `int` and then back to a `float`, forcing truncation towards zero.

Comment: @DannyRe - Yes...but the value is still truncated because you store the result as an int. You the cast the truncated data back to a float (with the inherent data loss intact). If you want no loss, simply change the method body to a one liner: return length * width;

Comment: @DannyRe: The `result =` part causes a conversion from `float` to `int`, and that causes the approximately 0.01 to be forgotten.  Then yes, the `return result;` part causes a conversion from `int` to `float`, since the return type is `float`.