# Template parameter as a friend

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, friend

In C++03 the following is illegal, although some compilers support it.

```
template <class T>
class X
{
    friend T;
};
```

Has this been legalized in C++11? (Sorry, didn't have time to read the draft myself, just hoping someone knows this)

Comment: [tag:friend] is correct for C++.

Comment: [friends](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/friends) is for Facebook.

Comment: @Ken: I'm glad it's not for the TV Show xD

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From section §11.3, 3 in N3291:

```
template <typename T> class R {
  friend T;
};

R<C> rc; // class C is a friend of R<C>
R<int> Ri; // OK: "friend int;" is ignored
```

So it is legal in C++11.

Comment: I am very glad `friend int;` is ignored :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes c++0x allows template parameter to be friends.

Well, I happened to remember read it in the draft before but could not find the reference..anyways @Praetorian's answer nailed it.

Answer (score 0):

It is illegal in plain C++, but there is a simple workaround

```
template <class T>
class X
{
    private:
        class Wrapper
        {
            public:
                typedef T Type;
        };
        friend class Wrapper::Type;
};
```

Comment: Works on gcc but not on VC2010 and Comeau

Comment: Yeah, tried it on Clang as well, didn't work :( - Apparently the standard forbids befriending typedef'd types which the GCC does not check for. However it is permitted to write `friend T;` which GCC does not recognize, but Clang does.