# Templatize the friendship in C++

Tags: c++, templates, friend

Is it possible to make the friend class a template, such as :

```
template <class T>
class MyClass {
public:
    friend class T;
};
```

The reason why I'm striving to get this is that I'm using [policy-based design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy_based_design) and I want my policy classes to access the host members. 
(...now I begin to think that this might mean my design is simply bad... )

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: There is a way : use [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)

Comment: If T and MyClass can have a common base class I guess CRTP is a nice solution!

Comment: it is [allowed now](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6510041/template-parameter-as-a-friend)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++03 you are not allowed to declare friendship to an argument of the template.

> §7.1.5.3/2
>
> [...] If the identifier resolves to a typedef- name or a template type-parameter, the elaborated-type-specifier is ill-formed. [Note: this implies that, within a class template with a template type-parameter T, the declaration

```
       friend class T;
```

is ill-formed. ]

In C++11 there has been some changes to this respect, but it is a bit weird. `friend class T;` is still illformed, but `friend T` is allowed. A quote can be found in the same paragraph:

> §7.1.5.3/2
>
> [...] [ Note: This implies that, within a class template with a template type-parameter T, the declaration

```
 friend class T;
```

> is ill-formed. However, the similar declaration friend T; is allowed (11.3). — end note ]

Notes are not normative, but they indicate the intent of the norms around it. I have not been able to find the specific sentence that makes the note correct, but I assume that *at least the intention* is that this should be allowed.

Comment: Weird indeed, but practical in my case :) Thank you David.