# Working on a solid Command Pattern with shared_ptr

Tags: c++, design-patterns, shared-ptr, command-pattern

I am trying to implement a very clean Command Pattern in a library.

I have the following structure right now (a few parts are still being finished up):

1. users (client-code) have some Object, call it "Manager"
2. `Manager` holds a collection of `shared_ptr<Foo>`
3. `Manager` provides access to the collection by returning `shared_ptr<Foo>`
4. I have a `Command` abstract class and a hierarchy of commands for actions to perform on `Foo`
5. Client code **should not** call `Command::execute()`, only `Manager` **should**, `Manager::execute(shared_ptr<Command>)`, so that it can handle undo/redo

I would like to follow the following rules:

1. users (client-code) have some Object, call it "Manager"
2. `Manager` holds a collection of `shared_ptr<Foo>`
3. `Manager` provides access to the collection by returning `shared_ptr<const Foo>`
4. I have a `Command` abstract class and a hierarchy of commands for actions to perform on `Foo`
5. Client code **cannot** (without workarounds) call `Command::execute()`, only `Manager` **can**, `Manager::execute(shared_ptr<Command>)`, so that it can handle undo/redo and get non-const smart pointers
6. A `Manager` must be able to allow `Command` objects to access and modify `shared_ptr<Foo>` even though the user initializes `Command` objecst with `shared_ptr<const Foo>`

I am just trying to figure out the best way to handle giving out `shared_ptr<const Foo>` while allowing number 5 and 6 to work.

Is there any example/design pattern that does this which I could learn from? Is this a good idea compared to what I already have/am working on?

Comment: Instead of giving out `shared_ptr<const Foo>`, could you instead give out a key or index into the container from where it came? This would prevent having to deal with `const_cast` and its potential pitfalls.

Comment: @Emile Cormier I think that actually just handing out keys or indices would be a good idea.  The only problem (possibly), is that I think I may want client code to be able to access the const members to read values.  That's why having const pointers is nice.  I would like to avoid const_cast by doing a lookup by pointer potentially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it wouldn't make any sense to me otherwise, I'm going to assume that

- your library provides the `Manager` class (or at least a base class), and
- clients have to use that class to invoke a `Command`.

In that case, maybe something like this could work:

```
void Manager::execute(Command& cmd, shared_ptr<Foo const> const& target)
{
    shared_ptr<Foo> mutableTarget = this->LookupMutableFoo(mutableTarget); // throws if not found
    cmd.execute(mutableTarget); // client cannot invoke without mutable pointer
}

// or, if the "target" needs to be stored in the Command you could use something like this:
void Manager::execute(Command& cmd)
{
    shared_ptr<Foo> mutableTarget = this->LookupMutableFoo(cmd.GetTarget()); // throws if not found
    cmd.execute(mutableTarget); // client cannot invoke without mutable pointer
}
```

I'm not sure though if using `const` is the best solution here. Maybe you should wrap your `Foo` objects in e.g. `ClientFoo` objects. The manager only hands out pointers to `ClientFoo`. The manager can then (e.g. via `friend`) get the `Foo` from the `ClientFoo`, and use it to invoke the `Command`.

Comment: That's almost how I'd like it.  I'm trying to decide though as to whether all Commands will have a single `shared_ptr<Foo>` target so I can pass it in to execute or not.  It is nice that essentially no client can invoke `command.execute(...)` because they cannot get the non-const pointer.

Comment: Also, why do you recommend a wrapper class over `const`?  I can see how I can get the same end result either way (I only expose methods that are const in `Foo`).

Comment: Mainly because the `LookupMutableFoo` method feels kind of "dirty" (or at least strange) :) In addition, using a distinct class is much more flexible then using `const`. But as I wrote, I'm not sure - I'd have to know much more about what you're trying to do to be sure.

Comment: If I have a `std::set<std::shared_ptr<Foo> >` and I want to find a `std::shared_ptr<const Foo>`, will that work "out of the box?  I know that Set is efficient at finding items (it's stored as a red-black tree or something?), but also that those types may be "incompatible".  I was just wondering if I could use `set::find`.

Comment: No, won't work. You can `const_pointer_cast` the `shared_ptr`, and then just make sure that it's contained in the `set`. Or you can use a boost intrusive set: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/intrusive/advanced_lookups_insertions.html#intrusive.advanced_lookups_insertions.advanced_lookups

Comment: @pgroke I see.  Luckily I realized it made sense to store a `std::map<Key, std::shared_ptr<Foo> >` where I can get the `Key` from a `const Foo`.  Now the table lookup makes sense, and client code can access the members of `const Foo` (rather than just holding some key)

Answer (score 2):

I think this [`passkey pattern`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324898/can-we-increase-the-re-usability-of-this-key-oriented-access-protection-pattern) should be the right thing for you:

```
class CommandExecuteKey{
private:
  friend class Manager;
  CommandExecuteKey(){}
};

class Command{
public:
  // usual stuff
  void execute(CommandExecuteKey);
};

class Manager{
public
  void execute(Command& cmd){
    // do whatever you need to do
    cmd.execute(CommandExecuteKey());
  }
};
```

Now, `Command` doesn't know anything about `Manager`, only about the key that is needed for the `execute` function. The user won't be able to call the `execute` method directly, as only `Manager` can create `CommandExecuteKey` objects, thanks to a private constructor and `friend`ship.

```
int main(){
  Command cmd;
  Manager mgr;
  //cmd.execute(CommandExecuteKey()); // error: constructor not accessible
  mgr.execute(cmd); // works fine, Manager can create a key
}
```

---

Now, for your 6th point:
When you get the command in, search all your `shared_ptr<Foo>`s for the correct object (using the saved `shared_ptr` of the command as a search-key) and then pass that mutable one from your internal `shared_ptr`s back to the command.

Comment: It seems that Command still *transitively* knows about Manager (via CommandExecuteKey). But this an interesting pattern, nonetheless. I've never heard of it before.

Comment: @Emile: Well, you know whom you hand your front-door keys to, too, no? ;) One advantage is, that you can easily swap the underlying friended class without `Command` ever noticing. The same with your front-door, it will never know whom you hand keys to.

Comment: Hehe. :-) Oh I see now. It's like a friendship limited only to certain parts of the class. It's like me wanting to hand out my front door keys without having to give out my blood type and SSN. +1

Comment: @Emile: Correct, it allows fine grained control over who can do what with your class. :) The linked question goes into further explanations.

Comment: I do like this method, but I felt that the chosen answer fit better with what I want.  Still, this is a really cool trick, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not following your question 100%, but here goes...

The only thing I can think of for #5 is to make `Command::execute` private/protected and make `Manager` a `friend` of `Command`. The downside of this approach is that you've now introduced a dependency from `Command` to `Manager`.

As for #6, if the user's `shared_ptr<const Foo>` objects were originated from Manager's `shared_ptr<Foo>` collection, then `Manager` *should* be able to safely const_pointer_cast `shared_ptr<const Foo*>` back into `shared_ptr<Foo*>`. If Manager attempts to const cast a `shared_ptr<const Foo*>`, where the pointee is an actual constant object, you'll get undefined behavior.

---

I've thought of another solution for #5:

Define an `ExecutableCommand` class, derived from `Command`. `ExecutableCommand` has an added method to invoke the command, to be used only by `Manager`. Clients can only access `ExecutableCommand` objects via pointers/references to `Command`. When a Manager wants to invoke a `Command`, it downcasts it to a `ExecutableCommand` to gain access to the invocation interface.

Working example (including const_pointer_cast for #6):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct Foo
{
    Foo(int x) : x(x) {}
    void print() {++x; cout << "x = " << x << "\n";} // non-const
    int x;
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct Command
{
    // Interface accessible to users
    std::string name;

private:
    virtual void execute() = 0;
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct ExecutableCommand : public Command
{
    // Only accessible to Manager
    virtual void execute() {} // You may want to make this pure virtual
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct PrintCommand : public ExecutableCommand
{
    PrintCommand(shared_ptr<const Foo> foo)
        : foo_( const_pointer_cast<Foo>(foo) ) {}

    void execute() {foo_->print();}

private:
    shared_ptr<Foo> foo_;
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct Manager
{
    void execute(Command& command)
    {
        ExecutableCommand& ecmd = dynamic_cast<ExecutableCommand&>(command);
        ecmd.execute();
    }

    void addFoo(shared_ptr<Foo> foo) {fooVec.push_back(foo);}

    shared_ptr<const Foo> getFoo(size_t index) {return fooVec.at(index);}

private:
    std::vector< shared_ptr<Foo> > fooVec;
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main()
{
    Manager mgr;
    mgr.addFoo( shared_ptr<Foo>(new Foo(41)) );

    Command* print = new PrintCommand(mgr.getFoo(0));
    // print.execute() // Not allowed
    mgr.execute(*print);

    delete print;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be a problem that `Command` is a base class, so making `Manager` a `friend` wouldn't inherit (friendship doesn't inherit)?

Comment: If Manager only invokes commands via the Command base class, then this is not a problem.