# How can a class declare all of its variadic template parameters friends?

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, variadic-templates

If I have a class which takes variadic pack of template arguments how can I declare them all to be friends?

Here is what I would like to do in pseudo-code form:

```
template<typename... Ts>
class AbstractMyClass {
    int privateInt;
    friend Ts...;
};
class OtherClass;
using MyClass = AbstractMyClass<OtherClass>;

class OtherClass {
public:
    void foo(MyClass &c){
        c.privateInt = 42;
    }
};
```

Comment: A better idea than friending might be a [passkey](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3324984/500104) (the C++11 `allow` version).

Answer (score -1):

This can only be done using "compile time recursion", much like tuples. The gist is (I am on a small laptop right now and by no means able to comfortably type):

```
template<class .... THINGS> class object;

template<class T> class object {
    friend T;
};

template<class T,class ... THINGS>
class object: public object<THINGS> {
    friend T;
};
```

If C++ doesn't like that, try `template<> class object<> {};` as the one that ends the recursion (I terminate it with an `object` in 1 template paramater)

(Thanks to Dietmar Kuhl for formatting)

Comment: I think the termination case "template<class T> class object" needs to hold the formerly private section ('privateInt' in this case) as a protected member in order for all the friends to access it. Make that change and I will accept.

Comment: This is so far removed from anything compilable that I felt compelled to downvote it six years later.

Comment: @Peter forgive my comments if you were just desperately copying and pasting and hoping for it to compile ;)

Comment: Also @peter anyone who writes template<class A,class B> class thing<B,A> should be shot.

Comment: Curiously my comment about @Peter 's awesome (it did inspire awe) to not understand "template<class T> class object {" when followed by one line/one statement, then "};" which was longer than the diff would be to produce those changes has somehow vanished. Good luck Peter.