# Objective-C++ 11 - Why can't we assign a block to a lambda?

Tags: c++, objective-c, lambda, c++11, objective-c++

So, I just upgraded to Xcode 4.4, and I noticed in the changelog:

> Apple LLVM compiler supports additional C++11 features, including lambdas

Which is awesome! So I got around to coding, and I found a few things out:

1. Lambdas are assignable to Objective-C blocks:

   ```
   void (^block)() = []() -> void { 
       NSLog(@"Inside Lambda called as block!");
   };

   block();
   ```
2. `std::function` can hold an Objective-C block:

   ```
   std::function<void(void)> func = ^{
       NSLog(@"Block inside std::function");
   };

   func();
   ```
3. We cant assign an Objective-C block to a lambda:

   ```
   auto lambda = []() -> {
       NSLog(@"Lambda!");
   };

   lambda = ^{ // error!
       NSLog(@"Block!");
   };

   lambda();
   ```

Why is this? Shouldn't the two be semantically equivalent, given what we've seen above?

Comment: +1 Awesome news, great question - can't wait to see more on this subject.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

C++11's lambda's copy-assignment operator is explicitly disabled<sup>1</sup>. This is not a matter of "semantically equivalent". It can't even assign back to itself. Not to mention an unrelated type.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <type_traits>

int main() {
    auto lambda1 = []() -> void { printf("Lambda 1!\n"); };
    lambda1 = lambda1;  // error: use of deleted function ‘main()::<lambda()>& main()::<lambda()>::operator=(const main()::<lambda()>&)’
    return 0;
}
```

---

`std::function` can hold an Objective-C block.

- `std::function` can hold any types which can be invoked as `f(a,b,c,...)`. Since blocks support "the invoke operator", it can also be held by a `std::function`. But notice that Objective-C and C++ follow different memory management scheme, so storing a block in a `std::function` for a long time may cause dangling reference.

---

Lambdas are assignable to Objective-C blocks:

- Blame [SAHChandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148242/is-it-possible-to-convert-a-c0x-lambda-to-a-clang-block)<sup>2</sup> :). It's not documented yet, though.

---

<sup>1</sup>: C++11 §5.1.2/19:

> The closure type associated with a *lambda-expression* has a deleted (8.4.3) default constructor and a deleted copy assignment operator.

<sup>2</sup>: http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=rev&revision=150620

Answer (score 3):

Lambdas have their own, implementation-defined types which are specific to each lambda.  The following code is also an error:

```
auto l1=[](){return 1;}
auto l2=[](){return 2;}
l1=l2; //Error
```

`std::function` is a wrapper which is designed to hold any callable type; you should use that to hold callables which may be of different types.

Comment: Also of note: non-capturing lambdas (like those in this example) can be implicitly converted to function pointer types on assignment – e.g. `using fp_t = std::add_pointer_t<int(void)>; fp_t fp = l1;` would work in this case. If the lambda is declared as capturing (like say `int x = 42; auto l3 = [&x](){ return x; }`) there is no equivalent function pointer type – a `std::function` instance is necessary to hold a capturing lambda.