# What do ^() {} and ^{} mean in C++?

Tags: c++

I recently read some C++ code like this:

```
setData(total, &user, ^() {
  struct dst_t to = {ip, port};
  sendData(to, data);
});


getData(total, ^{
  recvData(data, NULL);
});
```

I've never seen `^() {}` nor `^{}`. What do they mean? Some kind of anonymous function?

Comment: Is this *managed* C++, a.k.a. C++/CLI?  Is this C#?

Comment: `^` sure looks like a macro, try to scan through `#define` statements. In fact you can run `gcc` with the `-E` option to expand macros: `g++ -E main.cpp`

Comment: Is this compiled with clang?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocks_(C_language_extension)

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes, seems it's clang

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I think it's c++...

Comment: Perhaps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201514/block-declaration-syntax-list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to find a duplicate with `^() {}` symbols, so I'll post an answer.

These are "blocks", which is a clang compiler extension that creates lambda-like closures.

More info at [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocks_(C_language_extension)) and in [clangs Language Specification for Blocks](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/BlockLanguageSpec.html).

When there is an empty argument list, the `(void)` can be omitted, the `^ { recvData(data, NULL); }` is the same as `^ void (void) { recvData(data, NULL); }`.

Comment: Note that while they work in C & C++ code, they were primarily designed around an objective-c world, and if you're using C++, you should almost certainly use the much more idiomatic lambdas and std::function instead of these (though note that [std::function can hold blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11669292/objective-c-11-why-cant-we-assign-a-block-to-a-lambda))