# Cannot pass lambda function as function reference?

Tags: c++, c++11

Passing the lambda as function pointer works fine with gcc 4.6.3:

```
#example adapt from LoudNPossiblyWrong http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351280/c0x-lambda-to-function-pointer-in-vs-2010
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void func(int i){cout << "I'V BEEN CALLED: " << i <<endl;}

void fptrfunc(void (*fptr)(int i), int j){fptr(j);}

int main(){
    fptrfunc(func,10); //this is ok
    fptrfunc([](int i){cout << "LAMBDA CALL " << i << endl; }, 20); //works fine
    return 0;
}
```

However passing the lambda as reference will not work:

```
#example adapt from LoudNPossiblyWrong http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351280/c0x-lambda-to-function-pointer-in-vs-2010
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void func(int i){cout << "I'V BEEN CALLED: " << i <<endl;}

void freffunc(void (&fptr)(int i), int j){fptr(j);}

int main(){
    freffunc(func,10); //this is ok
    freffunc([](int i){cout << "LAMBDA CALL " << i << endl; }, 20); //DOES NOT COMPILE
    return 0;
}
```

error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type `‘void (&)(int)’` from an rvalue of type `‘<lambda(int)>’`

Can anyone explain why is that?

Comment: rvalue/temporary cannot bind to non-const reference

Comment: Try adding an asterisk, like `*[](int i){/*...*/}`. No idea if that works...

Comment: @yngum, if this is the issue. I will expect the `void (&&fptr)(int i)` solve the problem. But it does not.
@Kerrek, this actually works. Maybe this is because @Angew said, the closure object has conversion operator from closure=>pointer but not closure=>reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lambda is not really a function, it's a *closure object.* Basically, a compiler-generated class with `operator()` defined. A non-capturing closure also defines a conversion operator for converting to good old pointer-to-function.

Comment: thanks a lot! you seem correct. Can you tell me where can I find the document/source of this conversion operator of closure/function object?

Comment: @Wang The operator is required by C++11 standard, [expr.prim.lambda]§6. The almost-final draft of the standard can be obtained for free from [open-std.org](http://www.open-std.org/).