# How could vc2015+ support operator implicit convertion with decltype(*)?

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype

When I tested the code with https://stackoverflow.com/a/3351627/4423987, I found the code can not be compiled success through vc2015 and vc2017. On the same time, clang 3.8.0 and g++  5.4.0 works fine.

```
   #include <functional>
#include <iostream>

namespace detail{
template<typename Lambda, typename Func>
struct lambda_wrapper;


template <typename Lambda, typename C, typename R>
struct lambda_wrapper<Lambda,R (C::*)(void) const>{
    static R call(void){
        Lambda x;
        return x();
    }
     //typedef decltype(&call) function_type;  this line of code works fine under g++ and clang but vc2015+
    using function_type= R (*)(void); 
    operator function_type (void) const { return &call;}
};

 template <typename Lambda, typename C, typename R,
                typename A0>
    struct lambda_wrapper<Lambda, R (C::*)(A0) const>
    {
        static R call(A0&& p0)
        {
             Lambda x;
            return x(std::forward<A0>(p0));
        }

    //typedef decltype(&call) function_type;  this line of code works fine under g++ and clang but vc2015+
    using function_type= R (*)(A0&&); 
    operator function_type (void) const { return &call;}
    };
}//end of namespace detail
template <typename Lambda>
struct lambda_wrapper
    :detail::lambda_wrapper<Lambda, decltype(&Lambda::operator())>{};

template <typename Lambda>
lambda_wrapper<Lambda> wrap_lambda(const Lambda&){
    return lambda_wrapper<Lambda>();
}
int main(void)
{
    typedef void(*Ptr)();
    auto l = [](){ std::cout << "im broked :(" << std::endl; };
  //Ptr f=l;
    Ptr f=wrap_lambda(l);
    f();

    typedef void(*Ptr1)(int i);
    auto l1 = [](int i){ std::cout << "im happy :)" << i<<std::endl; };
   //Ptr1 f1=l1;
    Ptr1 f1=wrap_lambda(l1);
    f1(3);
}
```

compile under vc2015 made errors as follows:

source_file.cpp(54): error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'lambda_wrapper>' to 'Ptr1'
source_file.cpp(54): note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.23506 for x64

**

### What was wrong with vc2015+?

**

> Thanks to VTT. The convertion of lambda having no paras was ok, How about the convertion of lambda having paras? The sample code  was on 
>   http://rextester.com/MUTT25014

Comment: We all know that compilers still have bugs and conformance problems (this is especially true for Visual C++) so things like this may happen. You may want to report this issue on MS connect and hope that they'll fix it eventually. Or use `using function_type = R (*)(void);` as a workaround.

Comment: using function_type = R (*)(void) ---- solve the prolem with convertion  of lambda having no paras. But how about the convertion of lambda having paras?

Comment: This doesn't compile with gcc or clang.

Comment: `function_type` is a pointer to a normal function, it supposed to store a pointer to a static member function and  it has nothing to do with lambda. Your new error message is not even caused by that line, it is caused by `return x(std::forward<A0>(p0));` statement, you can rewrite it like this `return x.operator ()(std::forward<A0>(p0));` Also notice that `Ptr1` does not match the value returned by `wrap_lambda(l1)` because it returns a pointer to function taking an rvalue reference.