# Lambda not found when defined in an inline function in G++ 4.7

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc4.7

I have the following function defined in a header file (the library it is part of aims at being header-only):

```
typedef bool (*FieldComparer)(const std::string&, const std::string&);

inline FieldComparer
GetComparer(const std::string& query, string& separator)
{
    if (query.find('=') != std::string::npos) {
        separator = "=";
        return [](const string& s1, const string& s2) { return s1 == s2; };
    }
    else if (query.find('^') != string::npos) {
        separator = "^";
        return [](const string& s1, const string& s2) { return boost::starts_with(s1, s2); };
    }
    else if (query.find('*') != string::npos) {
        separator = "*";
        return [](const string& s1, const string& s2) { return boost::contains(s1, s2); };
    }
    else if (query.find('!') != string::npos) {
        separator = "!";
        return [](const string& s1, const string& s2) { return s1 != s2; };
    }
    else
        throw std::invalid_argument("Search: could not find operator in query string.");
}


template <class Description>
inline void
Search(Table<Description>& table, const std::string& query,
        std::function<void(const std::string&)> callback, int begin, int limit)
{
    string separator;
    auto comparer = GetComparer(query, separator);

    ... do stuff with comparer ...
}
```

I am trying to compile a small simple program that includes this file but I get undefined references to all the lambdas at link time. When I say simple there's a single CPP that compiles but can't link. Here the first error:

```
obj/sample.o: In function `DataModel::GetComparer(std::string const&, std::string&)::{lambda(std::string const&, std::string const&)#1}::operator bool (*)(std::string const&, std::string const&)() const':
/home/julien/workspace_dma/src/DataModel/Search.h:23: undefined reference to `DataModel::GetComparer(std::string const&, std::string&)::{lambda(std::string const&, std::string const&)#1}::_FUN(std::string const&, std::string const&)'
```

It's happening since I have upgraded to GCC 4.7.2, it used to work fine in GCC 4.6.2 (Ubuntu versions in case that helps). While I know workarounds to solve the problem, I am wondering what I am doing wrong or not understand properly. Since the lambas are inside the inline function they should be defined in any translation unit that uses that function.

-- EDIT --

One more thing worth noting: the `Search` and `GetComparer` function are not used in the sample program.

`Search` is used in a member function of `Table<Description>` (I can't post the full class):

```
template <class Description>
void Table<Description>::Search(const std::string& query,
        std::function<void(const std::string&)> callback, int begin, int count)
{
    DataModel::Search(*this, query, callback, begin, count);
}
```

But neither are called from the sample.cpp file. That file test other features of `Table` which are unrelated. If I comment the call in the member, the code compiles and links. (I need the member function, it's virtual, it's part of a type erasure class above `Table`).

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853186/conversion-of-lambda-expression-to-function-pointer

Comment: @Robᵩ: while it's *related* I don't think it's relevant. That other question is about a shortcoming of Visual C++ 10.0 plus about a lambda with capture. This question is about a g++ compiler bug.

Comment: @J.N. could you please post a complete example program, if practical?

Comment: I'll try, but I may not be able to due to confidentiality of some parts ... Many thanks for helping.

Comment: Example posted by Someone Else in the C++ Lounge: http://liveworkspace.org/code/35374b3c9b0d40e8ccc0819eb44d7f9e

Comment: I get the same error with a simple `main` program that calls `GetComparer`. The error disappears if I use a function object, rather than a function pointer: `tyepdef std::function<bool(const std::string&, const std::string&)> FieldComparer;`.

Comment: It's clearly a g++ bug. But proving that from the standardese may be hard.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf example compiles for me with gcc 4.7.0 under MinGW.

Comment: Please, report the bug to http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/ so that it has some chance of getting fixed. Posting questions here may help in getting peoples' attention, but there is no answer that will fix your compiler.

Comment: @jpalecek : I was blaming myself up till 5 minutes ago, not the compiler ;)

Comment: @J.N Have you tried removing the `inline`? That seems to fix the problem on the liveworkspace link. Still, looks like you've found a compiler bug.

Comment: @Yuushi : no because unlike the liveworkspace stuff my code is in a header file, the `inline` is required. That library was meant to be header only ... I'll see if it's worth changing or not ;)

Comment: @J.N. LucDanton mentioned in the C++ lounge that changing the function to internal linkage fixes the problem, and it [seems to compile](http://liveworkspace.org/code/2878cd54827b8cc8f7d6aeecda41c89c) at least if you do that. Maybe that's an option for you?

Comment: Bug reported at http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55015

Comment: @Praetorian It completely solves the problem, and it's acceptable for me. Using an anonymous namespace works as well (unsurprisingly).

Comment: Minimal testcase: http://liveworkspace.org/code/6d685397296f6f7b330fefd208d4b4d0

Comment: @Praetorian I suggest you post an answer (perhaps also mentioning that this is a compiler bug). You could get your well-deserved rep points and the question would no longer appear as unanswered.

Comment: @MartinStettner As I mentioned in the comment, it was LucDanton that figured that out. He should be the one posting an answer.

Comment: As far as I know they do: anonymous namespaces are equivalent to static because both make the object they describe visible only in the current translation unit only.

Comment: @ildjarn : thanks for the precisions. For my information, is that mandated by the standard ?

Comment: @ildjarn That unnamed namespaces imply internal linkage is a C++11 standardization of a previous, widely adopted non-conforming (but impossible to observe just from C++) practice. See 3.5 Program and linkage [basic.link] paragraph 4.

Comment: @Luc : Ah, I didn't realize that change was present in C++11. Today I learned, thanks.

Comment: This bug has [now been fixed](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55015#c13) for GCC 4.7.3. Good job everyone!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [bug report](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55015) has been filed with the GCC team, and one of the developers has [confirmed the issue on trunk](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55015#c3).

In the mean time, as LucDanton pointed out in chat, declaring the function `static` will solve the problem.